# I want access tokens with multiple scopes including http

Tags: azure, active-directory

·Task 
I want to include multiple scopes and allow access for those scopes with the same access token.
I have configured Azure Active Directory as per the attached image.
This condition was specified as follows, and an access token was issued with multiple scopes included.

```css
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"
--data-urlencode "client_id=<client_id>"
--data-urlencode "client_secret=<client_secret>"
--data-urlencode "username=testuser@thoughtspot.com"
--data-urlencode "password=*****"
--data-urlencode "grant_type=password"
--data-urlencode "scope=https://<application_id>/session:role-any email openid profile"
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_id>/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

When I visualized the issued access token on the following site, only session:role-any was included in the access token. 
https://jwt.ms/ 
By the way, when I included only the email openid profile in the scope, the email openid profile was included in the access token.

·question 
How can I include multiple (session:role-any email openid profile) tokens above in the access token? Also, is this even possible?

·Reference site 
https://docs.thoughtspot.com/cloud/latest/connections-snowflake-azure-ad-oauth 
I may be wrong. If so, please let me know the correct way of thinking.
[image]

Comment: An access token only works for one API. So you cannot include both MS Graph scopes and your API scopes in one token. You will need to get two tokens.

Answer (score 1):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

> I agree with **junnas**, access token does not work with multiple scopes. So, you need to generate two access token one for API and one for Graph.

I generated the access token for two scopes like below:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
username:admin@xxxx.onmicrosoft.com 
password:*****
grant_type:password
scope:api://*****/app.test email openid profile
```

[image]

> **Note** that: If you are passing two scopes, then it will consider only the first scope while generating the access token.

***The decoded access token shows only the API scope like below:***

[image]

The **`aud`** doesn't include Microsoft Graph scope and hence doesn't authorize Graph calls.

So, make sure to generate two access tokens separately, one for API scope and another for Graph scope.

I tried to generate the access token for the **Microsoft Graph scope** like below:

[image]

The decoded token contains Microsoft Graph scope and audience like below:

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer.
My perception was incorrect.
We will use this as a reference.