# AADSTS28004: The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' exceeded the number of scopes allowed

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, azure-active-directory, spring-cloud

[image]

I'm using [spring-cloud-azure-starter-active-directory](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.azure.spring/spring-cloud-azure-starter-active-directory) to integrate my webapp with azure AAD.

Previously my web app only need 3 api services, but when I add 1 more (webApi-4) I get this issue.
Is there any way to get out of this? I google for a while but can not find the solution.

This is my configuration yaml:
[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: If the web APIs have different applications then you need to generate the access token separately as one token can only be issued to one audience. You cannot acquire access token for multiple audience

Comment: You can include scopes for up to 3 resources in your login request refer this https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/1548

Comment: So there I have to get the token manually if I use that azure spring boot lib?

Comment: Yes you are right can I post it as an answer?

Comment: Yes Rukmini, maybe I will switch to client_credentials flow instead and use app role to author, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ***sample***, I used the below authorize endpoint to authorize the users:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=profile openid offline_access api://xxx/BEApp.access api://xxx/claim.read api://xxx/jango-test-api api://xxx/group.read
&state=12345
```

And got the **same error** as below:

[image]

The error ***"AADSTS28004: The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' exceeded the number of scopes allowed"*** usually occurs if you are scopes more than 3 resources in your login request. Refer this [**GitHub Blog**](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/1548) by *tnorling*.

> **Note** that: If the web APIs have different applications, then you need to generate the access token separately as one token can only be issued to one audience. You cannot acquire access token for multiple audience Refer this [**SO Thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75281958/i-want-access-tokens-with-multiple-scopes-including-http) by me.

You can make use of **client credential flow** and assign app role to the user like below:

Created a **Microsoft Entra application** and added an app role:

[image]

Exposed and API and added scope:

[image]

Granted API permissions:

[image]

Add the ***user to the role in the Enterprise application***:

[image]

Generated auth-code:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=api://ID/.default
&state=12345
```

[image]

Generated tokens like below:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID  
scope:api://ID/.default openid offline_access
grant_type:authorization_code  
code:code  
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
client_secret:Secret
```

[image]

**When I decoded the access token roles and scp is present:**

[image]

***Otherwise***, you can also make use of **client credential flow** and assign app role to user.